# Uncaught TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null

Tags: reactjs

I have a problem with react component,then,Uncaught TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null.I try to delet the 'extends React.Component',but It`s fale..thanks for your help.

````
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';

class Boss extends React.Component() {
    handlClick() {
        return alert('我是主页');
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div class="goto">
            </div>
        );
    }
    
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(<Boss />);```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is `React.Component` not `React.Component()`

```
class Boss extends React.Component{
//...
}
```